# Usar método de check out do Paypal para PagSeguro

Tags: php

Tenho um código e queria 'converter' para PagSeguro o Original é Paypal vou deixar abaixo o código:

```
if ($advert_sub == 'paypal') {
                $a = array('cmd' => '_xclick',
                           'business' => SITE_PAYPAL_EMAIL,
                           'currency_code' => SITE_CURRENCY,
                           'item_name' => '[Campaign ID: ' . $cid . '] ' . $website_name,
                           'amount' => $subtotal,
                           'notify_url' => SITE_PAYPAL_CALLBACK_URL,
                           'tax_rate' => Utilities::getVAT($subtotal),
                           'custom' => serialize(array('cid'=>$cid)),
                           'image_url' => SITE_PAYPAL_CHECKOUT_LOGO,
                           'cpp_ headerback_ color' => '2687be',
                           'no_shipping' => '1',
                           'return' => SITE_LOCATION . '?done',
                           'cancel_return' => SITE_LOCATION . '?cancelled'
                );
                $u = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?' . Utilities::arrayToURI($a);
                System::redirect($u);
            }
```

Então eu tava tentando mudar a URL, as variáveis mais não da, Ou o botão não funciona ou ele não aparece, Se tiverem como me ajudar eu agradeço.

Esse é o código de check out do pagseguro:

```
<!-- Declaração do formulário -->  
<form method="post" target="pagseguro"  
action="https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/checkout/payment.html">  

        <!-- Campos obrigatórios -->  
        <input name="receiverEmail" type="hidden" value="suporte@lojamodelo.com.br">  
        <input name="currency" type="hidden" value="BRL">  

        <!-- Itens do pagamento (ao menos um item é obrigatório) -->  
        <input name="itemId1" type="hidden" value="0001">  
        <input name="itemDescription1" type="hidden" value="Notebook Prata">  
        <input name="itemAmount1" type="hidden" value="24300.00">  
        <input name="itemQuantity1" type="hidden" value="1">  
        <input name="itemWeight1" type="hidden" value="1000">  
        <input name="itemId2" type="hidden" value="0002">  
        <input name="itemDescription2" type="hidden" value="Notebook Rosa">  
        <input name="itemAmount2" type="hidden" value="25600.00">  
        <input name="itemQuantity2" type="hidden" value="2">  
        <input name="itemWeight2" type="hidden" value="750">  

        <!-- Código de referência do pagamento no seu sistema (opcional) -->  
        <input name="reference" type="hidden" value="REF1234">  

        <!-- Informações de frete (opcionais) -->  
        <input name="shippingType" type="hidden" value="1">  
        <input name="shippingAddressPostalCode" type="hidden" value="01452002">  
        <input name="shippingAddressStreet" type="hidden" value="Av. Brig. Faria Lima">  
        <input name="shippingAddressNumber" type="hidden" value="1384">  
        <input name="shippingAddressComplement" type="hidden" value="5o andar">  
        <input name="shippingAddressDistrict" type="hidden" value="Jardim Paulistano">  
        <input name="shippingAddressCity" type="hidden" value="Sao Paulo">  
        <input name="shippingAddressState" type="hidden" value="SP">  
        <input name="shippingAddressCountry" type="hidden" value="BRA">  

        <!-- Dados do comprador (opcionais) -->  
        <input name="senderName" type="hidden" value="José Comprador">  
        <input name="senderAreaCode" type="hidden" value="11">  
        <input name="senderPhone" type="hidden" value="56273440">  
        <input name="senderEmail" type="hidden" value="comprador@uol.com.br">  

        <!-- submit do form (obrigatório) -->  
        <input alt="Pague com PagSeguro" name="submit"  type="image"  
src="https://p.simg.uol.com.br/out/pagseguro/i/botoes/pagamentos/120x53-pagar.gif"/>  

</form>
```

Comment: Coloque na sua dúvida o modelo de implementação do PagSeguro. Da maneira que está os visitantes terão que procurar como é a implementação do pagseguro.